# Support Images hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

I was going to edit [django-select2 not working with inlines in django-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562487/django-select2-not-working-with-inlines-in-django-admin) and replace the person's links to their screenshots with the images, when I realized the image uploader "from the web" option does not support Amazon S3.

So I am requesting that the feature be enhanced a bit to support a website such as awesomescreenshot.com (what the OP in the post used) and others which upload images on S3.

This is the link to the image: `http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/5701376?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1409292474&Signature=BiE0AGtljIBOmhGUxtKWi%2FfaEgI%3D`

For now I downloaded it and uploaded it as a normal file.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of the uploader failing, but I get an *AccessDenied / Request has expired* error when visiting that link.

Comment: im guessing that it won't be able to know what type that file is without requesting it.

Comment: @Stijn that's the other problem - if the link would be captured we wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Not sure if imgur issue